# Show mobile keyboard without input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, keyboard

I wanted to show the mobile keyboard in my responsive site. First at i tried to place a hidden input, with placeholder "tap here", but on this input i have an event, which when fires reloads the dom, and bucause of this a cannot able to show the keyboard.

The question is, there is a way to show the keyboard without an input? I'm using HTML5 doctype, and jQuery 2.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Why you want show keyboard without input? Set the keyboard visible if not used is a bad UX practice.

Comment: Anyway, you can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837543/show-virtual-keyboard-on-mobile-phones-in-javascript

Comment: Because i'm building a game, which is using keyboard (keycodes) without inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't open the keyboard without using a input. 
For more information you can read the following thread: 
[Show virtual keyboard on mobile phones in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837543/show-virtual-keyboard-on-mobile-phones-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If it is for a game, the best manner is create a propper layout with the buttons you want to use.