# JQuery show keyboard on mobile with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, keyboard

Hey guys I was following tutorial I found online on how to make Hangmen game and it was fine until I tested it on mobile. I just can't make virtual keyboard to show on mobile and I've already tried other answers to similar questions on stack. This is part of my code:

```js
$(document).on("click", function() {
  $('#dummy').focus();
});
$('#dummy').focus();
```

```css
#dummy {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topbar">Todemanija</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="gameContent"></div>
```

So guys is there a way to make this work. Also you can see full code in action here 
http://www.wpacademy.nextweb.space/TestingMobile/

Comment: where use `#dummy` ??

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6837575/2159528

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I've tried "If you trigger the .focus() from within a .click() event (e.g. from opening your dialog), the keyboard shows up" that's why I asked here maybe I'm doing something wrong idk

Comment: I think you absolutely need an `input` to focus on to get the mobile keyboard.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette So should I just make input field in HTML, hide it in CSS and use focus in JS ? Can that work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a text input to focus on to trigger the mobile keypad.
And you can't hide it, because a hidden input just can't be focussed.

**But!** I just had an idea you could try.

Add this to your `function gameScreen(){`:

```
$('#gameContent').append("<input type='text' id='dummy'>");
$("#dummy").css({"position":"fixed","left":"120%"}).focus();
```

So, the trick is to place the text input outside the viewport.

And you can remove this:

```
// with this function we add virtual keyboard for mobile users and we do not affect desktop gameplay
$(document).on("click",function() {
    $('#dummy').focus();
});
$('#startButton').click(function(e) {
    $('#dummy').trigger('click');
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is a small addition...
I tried your game after you added the previous answer.

In case the user looses the input focus during the game because of a `tap` outside the keyboard: add this, but outside `function gameScreen()` (at global scope):

function keepFocus(){

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).find("#dummy").focus();
},100);
```

}

At the end of `function gameScreen()`, to maintain the keyboard active:

```
$(document).on("touchstart", keepFocus);
```

At the end of `victoryMessage()` and `function defeatMessage()`, to deactivate the keyboard:

```
$(document).off("touchstart", keepFocus);
$("#dummy").blur();
```

Also, add this in your `start()` function:

```
$(document).on("touchstart", keepFocus);
```

Comment: It works thank you very much so basically my code didn't work because input is necessary for virtual keyboard to show ?

Comment: Yes... Here a list of mobile input and their associated [user interface](http://mobileinputtypes.com/).

Comment: Thank you. I'll look it up.

Comment: I've added a small addition... ;)

Comment: Thank you once again I didn't even think about that possibility :)

Comment: Hey men I don't know if you are still replying to comments but if you are I tried your solution to keep focus on keyboard when taped outside of keyboard and it doesn't work. Can you help me you can see the solution in action here http://www.wpacademy.nextweb.space/TestingMobile5/

Comment: ;) Just move the `keepFocus()` function above the `gameScreen()` function. It should work! --- It's because `keepFocus` is not yet defined in `$(document).on("tap", keepFocus);`.

Comment: Nope unfortunately that does not work :(    you can check it on link I've edited code there

Comment: Okay... I edited my answer with a tested solution about the mobile keyboard show/hide. It looks like `touchstart` event is better than `tap` for this... And a timeout is necessary to make it reappear automatically. Probably because there is an "animation" to make it appear. Tested on Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android).

Comment: Thank you very much from taking your time to help with this. It works now.