# How to determine whether a user has a keyboard attached in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div element that can get keyboard focus:

```
<div tabindex="0" onkeydown="myListener(event);">
    <span>Some display text</span>
</div>
```

My root problem is that mobile devices do not display the soft keyboard when a `<div>` gets focus, so I have written my own soft keyboard that I can display on focus and hide on blur.  But I would like to only display my soft keyboard if the user has no hard keyboard attached.

Is there any way for me to detect the absence of a physical keyboard?  Currently, I display the soft keyboard until I see a keyboard event, and then permanently hide the soft keyboard, but that's pretty inelegant.

Comment: Which `soft keyboard` did you use? Please add this code

Comment: I wrote my own soft keyboard; posting the code would just confuse the issue.  My question is how I can detect the absence of a hard keyboard; how I implemented my soft keyboard is irrelevant.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837543/show-virtual-keyboard-on-mobile-phones-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa setting focusto the DIV should display the soft keyboard.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to detect absence of a keyboard. Maybe just check if you're on a mobile device and assume it doesn't have a keyboard.

Comment: The stackoverflow thread referenced two above doesn't discuss DIV elements.  My problem is that there is a limited set of tags that result in the soft keyboard being displayed when they are focused (<input>, <textarea>, and several others) but <div> isn't one of them.

Comment: I believe that there is no way to detect is hard keyboard is present the same as you can't detect if virtual keyboard is open or not.