# Mobile Keyboard moves up, when I focus on the input tag

Tags: javascript

**HTML**

```
<input id="inputText" type="text" />
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('inputText').focus();
```

When My page is opened, I want to show the **mobile** keyboard by focusing on the `input` tag.

Comment: this seems only to work from an onclick event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837543/show-virtual-keyboard-on-mobile-phones-in-javascript