# How to prompt/show keyboard on mobile devices for event listeners?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a guide for a hangman game built using react...

I have a useEffect function which contains event listeners for keypresses.

However when viewing the page on mobile devices, there is no way to bring up the keyboard to actually press the keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6837575/8788847

Answer (score 0):

this is a tricky question

Try using the `.prompt()` method

see this tutorial

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp